# UDP frame loss in C++

Tags: c#, c++, server, udp

I have a C# code that takes data from UDP and counts lost frames if there is any. It works fine. I wrote the same code in C++ to see whether I get data faster than C# code or not.

However, before even comparing, I am having a problem; In C++ code, I lost a lot of frames.

In both code; I parse some part of the data as a user created header. A frame consists of 7 fragments. `FrameFragmentNo` counts segments in order. In C# code it counts 1,2,3..7 but in C++ it starts from 5 etc. and counts like 5,6 then new frame comes 1,6 etc. This means C++ code never takes frames properly.(C# code lost frames naturally but it is rare)`TotalFragmentCount` is also correct for both.

`safe_increment` is to count once when order is broken while counting the fragments of the frame. Don't mind `intData` it is about some process about rest of the data.

Interesting thing is when I trace C++ code, sometimes it does the counting correct. I suspected buffer size of windows OS but if that was the case, C# code shouldn't be working fine. I checked other posts, mostly people asked package loss, however I am having a frame loss. I also thought, maybe I take frames too fast but it couldn't come up with a solution.

Does anyone have any suggestion about this behaviour?

> This is the C# code works fine, counts fragments of frame in order

```
private void ReceiveData()
    {

        byte[] content;
        UInt16[] intData = new UInt16[0] { };
        UInt16 SkipFrameFlag = 1;


        dataReceiveThreadStarted = true;

        while (true)
        {
            content = udpClientData.Receive(ref IPEndPointDataReceiveInformation);//C# skips UDP header
            if (!DataReceiveEnabled)
            {
                continue;
            }

            //-------------------Parse User Created Header---------------------------
            MessageID = (UInt16)(content[0] << 8 | content[1]);
            FrameCount = (UInt32)(content[2] << 24 | content[3] << 16 | content[4] << 8 | content[5] << 0);
            TotalFragmentCount = (UInt16)(content[6] << 8 | content[7]);
            FrameFragmentNo = (UInt16)(content[8] << 8 | content[9]);
            Reserved = (UInt16)(content[10] << 8 | content[11]);
            MessageLength = (UInt16)(content[12] << 8 | content[13]);


            if (FrameFragmentNo == 1 && SkipFrameFlag == 1)  // After the skip flag, catch the start of frame.
            {

                SkipFrameFlag = 0;
                PrevFrameFragmentNo = 0;
                safe_increment = true;
                Array.Clear(intData, 0, intData.Length);
            }
            //Fragment is lost. Skip Frame
            if (FrameFragmentNo != (PrevFrameFragmentNo + 1)) {
                SkipFrameFlag = 1;

                //increment once when a frame is lost
                if (safe_increment)
                {
                    lostFrameCount++;
                    safe_increment = false;
                }
            } 


            if (SkipFrameFlag == 1)
                continue;

            if (FrameFragmentNo == TotalFragmentCount && intData != null) // Frame Fragmentation Completed
            {
                ragmentNo = 0;
                PrevFrameCount = FrameCount;
                ReceivedFrameCount++;
                ReceivedFrameLen = intData.Length;
        }
    }
```

> This is C++ code that lost too many frames or it takes too fast I
>   don't know

```
while (true)
{
    ZeroMemory(&client, clientLength); // Clear the client structure
    ZeroMemory(buf, 1550); // Clear the receive buffer

    // Wait for message
    int bytesIn = recvfrom(in, buf, 1550, 0, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientLength);

    if (bytesIn == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Error receiving from client " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        continue;
    }


    //-------------------Parse User Created Header----------------------
    MessageID = (uint16_t)(buf[0] << 8 | buf[1]);
    FrameCount = (uint32_t)(buf[2] << 24 | buf[3] << 16 | buf[4] << 8 | buf[5] << 0);
    TotalFragmentCount = (uint16_t)(buf[6] << 8 | buf[7]);
    FrameFragmentNo = (uint16_t)(buf[8] << 8 | buf[9]);
    Reserved = (uint16_t)(buf[10] << 8 | buf[11]);
    MessageLength = (uint16_t)(buf[12] << 8 | buf[13]);


    if (FrameFragmentNo == 1 && SkipFrameFlag == 1)  // After the skip flag, catch the start of frame.
    {
        SkipFrameFlag = 0;
        PrevFrameFragmentNo = 0;
        safe_increment = true;
        intData.clear();

    }

    if (FrameFragmentNo != (PrevFrameFragmentNo + 1)) //Fragment is lost. Skip Frame
    {
        SkipFrameFlag = 1;
        if (safe_increment) {
            lostFrameCount++;
            safe_increment = false;
        }

    }


    if (SkipFrameFlag == 1)
        continue;



if (FrameFragmentNo == TotalFragmentCount && intData.size() != 0) // Frame Fragmentation Completed
    {
        PrevFrameFragmentNo = 0;
        PrevFrameCount = FrameCount;
        ReceivedFrameCount++;
        ReceivedFrameLen = intData.size();

    }
 }
```

Comment: First frame of data you may have to flush the 5 & 6 to align data.  You want to start processing data when you only get the 1 & 2.  When in continuous mode you always need to align data.  Also with UDP you may not get all the data in one chunk and should not throw away partial data.  You  should be merging the data and then processing.

Comment: by flushing do you mean `ZeroMemory`

Comment: I mean throwing away the received data until the first fragment is found.  As I said "DO NOT THROW AWAY PARTIAL DATA".  You will end up loosing data.  It is acceptable at beginning of application deleting characters until you find the first fragment.  But then do not throw away anything unless there are errors and you need to align the data again.  Always investigate when you have to realign to see if there are errors in the code (or possibly at other end of connection).  But realignment should be a very rare occurrence except on startup.

Comment: @jdweng I am trying to figure out where do I "throw data" do you mean `intData.clear();` if so I save previous fragments in another array(I didn't upload that part since it is not related and too long), intData has no relation with frame loss.

Comment: I didn't saying you were throwing away data in your code.  I didn't really look at your code was just explaining the theory of communications.  I was concerned that you were getting lost frames.  You should never use the synchronous Receive Method in windows.  I have been having issue with Synchronous methods with Microsoft software for 40 years.  Always use Asynchronous method!!!  Synchronous method you will loose data!!!

Comment: @jdweng okay I see, I will try to find an asynchronous way, thank you